# How to change size of QPixmap?

Tags: qt

I am write a paint program.

```
pix = QPixmap(600,500);  // set size to 600X500
```

How to change size after this? Someting like:

```
pix.setSize(800,600);  // Change size to 800X600
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, [QPixmap::scaled](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled-1) is what you need.

Returns a copy of the pixmap scaled to a rectangle with the given width and height according to the given aspectRatioMode and transformMode.